# How do I unlock this electrical meter cabinet?

Tags: electrical, uk

I have my electricity meter reading inside this box, which I am unable to open. Any idea how to open this?

[image]

Comment: A better photo of the actual lock would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You buy a [utility-key](http://www.maplin.co.uk/search?text=utility+key&x=0&y=0) (AKA [services cabinet key](http://www.screwfix.com/p/bahco-9-way-radiator-services-cabinet-key/1668f)) or poke around with needle-nosed pliers

[image]

The X shaped metal tool ([four-way utility-key](http://www.drapertools.com/product/03071/Expert-Professional-Utility-Key)) has four different key shapes commonly used. It also has a useful plastic adapter for hex drive and a two-ended flat/phillips bit.

The keys shown in my photo work on both gas and electric meter boxes in the UK, you can buy them in most hardware/DIY shops.